# How to tile floating windows

Tags: macos, mac, spaces, window-manager, productivity

In the application I write in (Ableton Live), there are always several floating windows open. ("Floating" in the OSX sense: ^F6 toggles through them).

I use them so often that I need a way to tile them, so that they maximize screen space.

The issue is that they're always different sizes, so their dimensions would have to be detected in order to be properly tiled.

I've looked many places and no luck. Mosaic, Divvy etc only work with regular windows, not floating windows. There *must* be a solution somewhere.

Would LOVE some help on this!

Regards,
Nathan

Answer (score 1):

First off, this assumes you're talking about panels (e.g. Preview's Info window), the kind that sometimes hide when you switch to a different app.

Also, do you want to tile *all* your windows, or only some of them?

If you want to tile all of them, [Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/amethyst) is a good solution. It's open source; I don't know if it supports those panels, but it should be possible to add support if it doesn't.

If you only want to mess with a few of your windows, [Spectacle](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle) is better. It's also open source, and **does** seem to support panels.